# Test time in Java. Change spock stub value

Tags: java, spring, spock, java-time

I have defined bean in my spring application.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.time.Clock;

@Configuration
public class ClockConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Clock getSystemDefaultZoneClock() {
        return Clock.systemDefaultZone();
    }
}
```

Then in my test I want to Stub this bean.

```
import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterConstants
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.mock.DetachedMockFactory

import java.time.Clock
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.LocalDateTime

import static java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault

@ActiveProfiles(profiles = JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_TEST)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@SpringBootTest(classes = [MyApp])
class ClockTest extends Specification {


    @Autowired
    Clock clock

    //2018-04-01 at 10:00am
    private static Instant REFERENCE_DATE_TIME = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 4, 1, 10, 0)
        .atZone(systemDefault())
        .toInstant()

    //2018-04-01 at 10:00am
    private static Instant OTHER_REFERENCE_DATE_TIME = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 4, 2, 10, 0)
        .atZone(systemDefault())
        .toInstant()

    def "should return different date"() {
        when:
        clock.instant() >> REFERENCE_DATE_TIME
        then:
        clock.instant() == REFERENCE_DATE_TIME
        when:
        clock.instant() >> OTHER_REFERENCE_DATE_TIME
        then:
        clock.instant() == OTHER_REFERENCE_DATE_TIME

    }


    @TestConfiguration
    static class Mocks {
        def detachedMockFactory = new DetachedMockFactory()

        @Bean
        Clock clock() {
            return detachedMockFactory.Stub(Clock)
        }
    }

}
```

This test fails, because of second assertions. My stubed bean returns value declared by first interactions.

1. I would like to understand why this interaction is not changed.
2. I am looking for ideas how to redesign application. My goal is to

   when:

   //stub Clock with some value.

   //Do some logic. Use clock multiple times.

   //Change Clock to another instance.

   //Do some other logic. Use clock multiple times.

   then:

   //Make some assertion. (for example check time difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I come up with solution where I am using feature where I can compute return value.

http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/all_in_one.html#_computing_return_values

and in there I replace returned value.

```
import spock.lang.Specification

import java.time.Clock
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.LocalDateTime

import static java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault

class ClockStubTest extends Specification {
    private static Instant REFERENCE_DATE_TIME = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 4, 1, 10, 0)
        .atZone(systemDefault())
        .toInstant()

    private static Instant OTHER_REFERENCE_DATE_TIME = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 4, 2, 10, 0)
        .atZone(systemDefault())
        .toInstant()

    Clock clock = Stub()

    def "should return different date"() {
        given:
        def now
        clock.instant() >> { now }
        when:
        now = REFERENCE_DATE_TIME
        then:
        clock.instant() == REFERENCE_DATE_TIME
        clock.instant() == REFERENCE_DATE_TIME

        when:
        now = OTHER_REFERENCE_DATE_TIME
        then:
        clock.instant() == OTHER_REFERENCE_DATE_TIME
        clock.instant() == OTHER_REFERENCE_DATE_TIME
        clock.instant() == OTHER_REFERENCE_DATE_TIME
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is more complex than necessary. It is up to you, of course, but I still prefer my simple solution. Furthermore, I think the test is hard to read your way.

Comment: Oh, `>> { now }` has totally different behaviour than `>>  now `

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding Spock. You can only declare interactions once one a given mock, stub or spy. But what you can do it declare s tub method to return a [sequence of values](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/all_in_one.html#_returning_sequences_of_values).

Removing the Spring (Boot) clutter from your test, just using plain Spock, it looks like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import spock.lang.Specification

import java.time.Clock
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.LocalDateTime

import static java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault

class ClockStubTest extends Specification {
  private static Instant REFERENCE_DATE_TIME = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 4, 1, 10, 0)
    .atZone(systemDefault())
    .toInstant()

  private static Instant OTHER_REFERENCE_DATE_TIME = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 4, 2, 10, 0)
    .atZone(systemDefault())
    .toInstant()

  Clock clock = Stub()

  def "should return different date"() {
    given:
    clock.instant() >>> [REFERENCE_DATE_TIME, OTHER_REFERENCE_DATE_TIME]
    expect:
    clock.instant() == REFERENCE_DATE_TIME
    clock.instant() == OTHER_REFERENCE_DATE_TIME
  }
}
```

Or you can also just declare the stub method when directly in the scope of the created stub:

```java
  // (...)

  Clock clock = Stub() {
    instant() >>> [REFERENCE_DATE_TIME, OTHER_REFERENCE_DATE_TIME]
  }

  def "should return different date"() {
    expect:
    clock.instant() == REFERENCE_DATE_TIME
    clock.instant() == OTHER_REFERENCE_DATE_TIME
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did know about sequence values, but I didn't like this solution. I have multiple places where I use clock. With sequence I will have to know exactly how many and ever time I will add some new occurrence I will have to edit the sequence.

Comment: I have provided question with "Spring (Boot) clutter", because I was hoping that there might be some option to dynamically replace bean in context or something like this.

Comment: The "clutter" term was not meant to be derogatory, but both the reason and solution for your problem are independent of Spring. No need to replace anything, just configure the mock/stub object correctly.

Comment: Thank you then for clarification. It helped me to come up with another solution.